Calculating mean value of overlapping polygons of one shapefile in QGIS
I have one shapefile with thousands of polygons in it. Some of them are overlapping. In some places, there are even up to four overlaps.
The polygons represent different types of land use (i.e. industry, agricultural, transportation etc.) or other information like the type of vegetation or areas that are protected landscapes.
So for example there could be a polygon representing a protected landscape partially overlapping another polygon representing a forest area.
I am trying to derive a potential risk (field in the attribute table) for groundwater resources for each type of polygon. In the areas where they overlap, I want the risk value for this area to be the mean of all overlapping polygons.
Any ideas on how to solve this?

I think this is what you are looking for: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/417135/238384
Note, that following this answer you get two overlapping features for each pari of polygons. So you need to filter the resulting layer.

I've got to frame challenge here -- It's all well and good to store different land use classes in one table, but when you also store vegetation types and protected areas in the same layer, you invite this problem. This should be three different layers, with different attribute tables, which can be overlaid at need
